# RecyclerView при скролле элементы Invisible становятся Visible

Tags: android, recyclerview, xamarin

`RecyclerView` отображает данные в виде стены как в приложении от `vk`. Есть пост с комментарием от пользователя об содержимого репоста и есть просто репост.
Так от когда нету комментария в axml стоит

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/post_repost_text_layout"
    **android:visibility="gone"**
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
```

когда пользователь комментирует запись, то в `RecyclerView` в адаптере и в `OnBindViewHolder` проверяется есть ли текст и если есть значит `View` с текстом `Visible`.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempText)){
    vh.PostRepostTextLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    vh.CommentToRepostText.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
}
```

где `tempText` - комментарий пользователя.

И наконец суть вопроса: при скролле пост без комментария который должен быть `Invisible`. Становится `Visible`, но в самом начале он `Invisible` и уже когда проскролишь вниз и назад он `Visible`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Списки для экономии памяти не сохраняют айтемы при скроллинге за экран. Вообщем, ваша логика не должна ограничивает одним `if`. На каждый `if` должен быть `else`.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempText)){
    vh.PostRepostTextLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    vh.CommentToRepostText.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
} else {
    vh.PostRepostTextLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
    vh.CommentToRepostText.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone
}
```

Comment: хех спасибо, так просто)